# Problem with Invoke-Command and Windows DNS

Tags: azure, powershell, dns

I want to create script to automate managing our private DNS (hosted on Azure ADDS) via Powershell. For the beginning I created a simple script to list all DNS records. I added Invoke-Command to run this script remotely on Azure machine and the problem began. Invoke-command connect with target machine, ADAdmin user authenticate properly (Azure limitation - only adadmin could manage DNS on machine), but unfortunately I cannot list records. I got error "Failed to enumerate zones from the server IP.". In the other hand, when I RDP to target machine using the same user and run script from Invoke command - DNS records are listed without any problems.

Could you help me with that ?

```
# set up variables
$DNSServer = #IP machine in Azure
$user = #ADAdmin username
$pass = #ADAdmin password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

# open session to remote host (where containers will be run)
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user, $pass)
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $DNSServer -Credential $cred
$env:ComputerName

Invoke-Command  -Session $session -Scriptblock {
   $env:ComputerName
$Zones = @(Get-DnsServerZone -ComputerName "Azure ADDS IP")
ForEach ($Zone in $Zones) {
Write-Host "`n$($Zone.ZoneName)" -ForegroundColor "Green"
$Zone | Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName "Azure ADDS IP"
}
}
Remove-PSSession -Session $session
# Show-Error $? "Can't remove PS session after uploading image & starting the container"

Pop-Location
Exit 0


end {
# Write-Host "End processing"
}
```

Comment: Do you run these scripts with admin permission on the local and Azure machines? Refer to https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9c77bf4d-2fc2-4ffc-9ddf-887625c99928/getdnsserverzone?forum=ITCG

Comment: i have similar issue. do you have updates on this?